# Generate a CSV/Excel having specified values in dropDown option at that column in Golang

Tags: excel, csv, go

How to generate a csv/excel in Golang, where in some of the columns in that csv/excel will have dropdown option, so that whoever try to add/update values on that column can use the values available in the dropdown list.

For example: below excel file where on Airline column has list of specified values in dropdown.

P.S: below excel was generated in java using poi-4.0.0.jar library

Edit 1: I have taken different approach to solve above problem, that are shared here https://go.dev/play/p/WD-qpXh6JNg

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by @andrew-arrow, i took a look at [tealeg](https://github.com/tealeg/xlsx) library and i was able to get desired result, complete code is [here](https://go.dev/play/p/o2yZq3BlUZB).

Thanks again @andrew-arrow :)

```
file := xlsx.NewFile()
sheet, _ := file.AddSheet("Sheet1")
row := sheet.AddRow()
cell := row.AddCell()
cell.Value = "Column 1"
cell = row.AddCell()
cell.Value = "Column 2 (Dropdown)"

dropdownValues := []string{"AI | AirIndia", "UK | Vistara"}

for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
    row := sheet.AddRow()
    cell := row.AddCell()
    cell.Value = fmt.Sprintf("Test %d", i)

    cell = row.AddCell()
    dd := xlsx.NewXlsxCellDataValidation(true)
    dd.SetDropList(dropdownValues)
    cell.SetDataValidation(dd)
}

file.Save("output.xlsx")
```

snapshot of output.xlsx
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/tealeg/xlsx"
)

func main() {
    file := xlsx.NewFile()
    sheet, _ := file.AddSheet("Sheet1")
    row := sheet.AddRow()
    cell := row.AddCell()
    cell.Value = "Column 1"
    cell = row.AddCell()
    cell.Value = "Column 2 (Dropdown)"

    dropdownValues := []string{"hi", "there"}

    for i := 0; i < 10; i++ {
        row := sheet.AddRow()
        cell := row.AddCell()
        cell.Value = fmt.Sprintf("Test %d", i)

        cell = row.AddCell()
        cell.SetDataValidationList(dropdownValues)
    }

  file.Save("output.xlsx")
}
```

Comment: can you please share which version you are using? bcz in the latest version, there is no method called SetDataValidationList(), it only has SetDataValidation() and has different arguments https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/tealeg/xlsx#Cell.SetDataValidation

Comment: oh yes there is good example here with latest stuff: https://github.com/tealeg/xlsx/blob/master/data_validation_test.go#L35

Comment: thanks @andrew-arrow for pointing me to this.I ignored this library since its mentioned in the repo as "(No longer maintained!)", and started looking at github.com/qax-os/excelize repo, as mentioned in the same repo, but was unsuccessful in getting the desired output from that library. With this library i was able to achieve what i wanted. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Drop Down list on Excel are DataValidations you can use this library :
https://github.com/qax-os/excelize/

Here is a simple example :

```
// create new file 
f := excelize.NewFile()
defer func() {
    if err := f.Close(); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}()
index, err := f.NewSheet("Sheet2")
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}
// Create the new Data Validation
dv := excelize.NewDataValidation(true)
// add the keys that you want for your droplist
myKeys := []string{"test,test2"}
// add the keys to your drop list
dv.SetDropList(myKeys)
// What cells will be the dropdown list
dv.Sqref = "A1:A1"
// Add the datavalidation to your sheet
f.AddDataValidation("Sheet2", dv)
f.SetActiveSheet(index)
f.SaveAs("bok1.xlsx")
```

Comment: hi @gatusko, code you have shared is giving errors during compile time, pls share the version of library you have used. i have updated my question with all the approaches i have already taken and failed. pls check that once